# How to extract the counter value for each section separately?

Tags: counters, setcounter

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%%% Main drive for pdflatex %%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09]
\usepackage{pgffor}
% \foreach \n in {0,...,22}{do something}
\usepackage[nonumberofruns]{xassoccnt}
%% length setup
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength{\qspace}
\setlength{\qspace}{20pt}
%\newcounter{qnumber}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{question}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\vspace{\qspace}
%\clearpage
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1\quad][10]%
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
    \item%
}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{enumerate}
    \filbreak
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\textsc{
In this paper:\\
There are 3 questions in section A. \\
There are 2 questions in section B. \\
There are 3 questions in section C. \\
There are \TotalValue{qnumber} questions in total.
}
\section*{Section A: \ \ \ Pure Mathematics}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}
\section*{Section B: \ \ \ XXXXXX}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 

\end{question}
\section*{Section C: \ \ \ XXXXX}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}
\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Is there a way to automatically get the values for these three values for each section，
so I don't have to work it out manually?

```
There are xxx questions in section A. \\
There are xxx questions in section B. \\
There are xxx questions in section C. \\
```

I am hoping to make a global change, i.e. change something in the definition before **\begin{document}** so I don't have to make changes in each file I already have.

I should also mention that I must **keep** the question numbers as it is. That is, they are **NOT TO BE** restarted from each of the new section*{}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to save the value of `qnumber` when a new section is started (and at end document as well).

It's easier if you define your own commands so you have also the benefit o f not needing manual formatting each time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09]

%% infrastructure
\newcounter{qsection}
\renewcommand{\theqsection}{\Alph{qsection}}

\newcommand{\qsection}[1]{%
  % save the value of qnumber
  \saveqnumber
  \stepcounter{qsection}%
  \section*{Section \theqsection:\quad #1}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\saveqnumber}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\saveqnumber}{}
 {
  \iow_shipout:cx { @auxout } { \QUESTIONS{\arabic{qsection}}{\arabic{qnumber}} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\QUESTIONS}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_casper_questions_seq { \RESUMESECTION{#1}{#2} }
  \int_gadd:Nn \g_casper_questions_int { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\RESUMESECTION}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 0 }
   {
    There~are~#2~questions~in~section~\int_to_Alph:n { #1 }.
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\QSECTIONS} { m }
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_casper_sections_int { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\resume}{}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}\scshape
  In~this~paper:\par
  \seq_use:Nn \g_casper_questions_seq { \par }
  \par
  There~are~\int_to_arabic:n { \g_casper_questions_int }~questions~in~total.
  \end{flushleft}
 }

\seq_new:N \g_casper_questions_seq
\int_new:N \g_casper_questions_int
\int_new:N \g_casper_sections_int

\ExplSyntaxOff

%% length setup
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength{\qspace}
\setlength{\qspace}{20pt}

% specific environment
\newcounter{qnumber}
\counterwithin{qnumber}{qsection}

\newenvironment{question}
 {\vspace{\qspace}
  \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1\quad][10]%
  \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
  \item
 }
 {\end{enumerate}
  \filbreak
  \stepcounter{qnumber}
}

\begin{document}

\resume

\qsection{Pure Mathematics}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}


\qsection{XXXXXX}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}


\qsection{XXXXX}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `.aux` file contains

```
\relax 
\QUESTIONS {0}{0}
\QUESTIONS {1}{3}
\QUESTIONS {2}{2}
\QUESTIONS {3}{3}
\gdef \@abspage@last{2}
```

where you see that the correct values are saved and used at the next run of LaTeX.

If you want to keep the `\section*` and manually number sections… replace the code after `%% infrastructure` with

```
%% infrastructure
\newcounter{qsection}
\renewcommand{\theqsection}{\Alph{qsection}}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  % save the value of qnumber
  \saveqnumber
  \stepcounter{qsection}%
  \latexsection
}
\AtEndDocument{\saveqnumber}
```

After this the code is the same.

A version where the question counter is not reset.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09]

%% infrastructure
\newcounter{qsection}
\renewcommand{\theqsection}{\Alph{qsection}}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  % save the value of qnumber
  \saveqnumber
  \stepcounter{qsection}%
  \latexsection
}
\AtEndDocument{\saveqnumber}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\saveqnumber}{}
 {
  \iow_shipout:cx { @auxout } { \QUESTIONS{\arabic{qsection}}{\arabic{qnumber}} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\QUESTIONS}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_casper_questions_seq
   {
    \RESUMESECTION{#1}{ \int_eval:n { #2 - \g_casper_questions_int } }
   }
  \int_gset:Nn \g_casper_questions_int { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\RESUMESECTION}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 0 }
   {
    There~are~#2~questions~in~section~\int_to_Alph:n { #1 }.
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\QSECTIONS} { m }
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_casper_sections_int { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\resume}{}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}\scshape
  In~this~paper:\par
  \seq_use:Nn \g_casper_questions_seq { \par }
  \par
  There~are~\int_to_arabic:n { \g_casper_questions_int }~questions~in~total.
  \end{flushleft}
 }

\seq_new:N \g_casper_questions_seq
\int_new:N \g_casper_questions_int
\int_new:N \g_casper_sections_int

\ExplSyntaxOff

%% length setup
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newlength{\qspace}
\setlength{\qspace}{20pt}

% specific environment
\newcounter{qnumber}

\newenvironment{question}
 {\vspace{\qspace}
  \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1\quad][10]%
  \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
  \item
 }
 {\end{enumerate}
  \filbreak
  \stepcounter{qnumber}
}

\begin{document}

\resume

\section*{Section A: Pure Mathematics}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}


\section*{Section B: XXXXXX}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}


\section*{Section C: XXXXX}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\begin{question}
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
some texts some texts some texts some texts some texts 
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's much more than what I actually need for my purpose! What should I look for to call out the value after using the *\saveqnumber*? I will play around with it.

Comment: hmmmmm. Also I then need to use search and replace for all the *\section*{} * I have in my hundreds of tex files. Any other simpler ways to achieve this similar result?

Comment: @CasperYC Bad design decision: are you sure you have always typed in the right number of “backslash space” commands? Repeated formatting should always be dealt with a new command.

Comment: If you are refering to the `Section B: \ \ \ XXXXXX` from the MWE, these are taken  from a very old tex file without thiniking too much. What I trying to say is could I achieve this without using *\qsection* and keeping the old \section*{xxxx} stuff. Could it be done with some save and restore?

Comment: @CasperYC I believe you *should* use `\qsection`, but I added the changes to the code to be made to keep `\section*`.

Comment: Just another quick comment. I have tried to see if in your code, I can disable the reset of the counter for each section, but I couldn't? This is another important requirement in my OP....once disabled \counterwithin in your case, the desired counter would not actually count correctly...

Comment: @CasperYC I added a version without reset of the question number.

Comment: Thank you very much.